# Unable to point Domain with CNAME and MX Record, what are my options?

Tags: dns, web-hosting, cname

I currently have a domain that is pointing to `"Web Host A"` using an IP in the A record and it has an `MX Record` which points to Google Apps Mail for email.  I want to point the domain to a new host `"Web Host B"`.  This Web Host B uses `CNAME` records instead of A records.  But I got an error message saying I can't have both a `CNAME` record and `MX record` present.  This was possible to have both using `A` record.  Now I'm stuck, what are my options??? I don't want to have to lose email or move email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I'm stuck, what are my options???

- Don't use CNAMEs. (Don't move to Web Host B, if that's all they support).
- Only use `www.` for web traffic, stop using the root domain for web traffic, and have no CNAME for the domain root.
- Move your email to a different domain or subdomain and remove your MX records.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use CNAME mainly because the domain is owned by someone else who wants to change hosts.  I like your advice of option #2, I didn't think about that actually.  Option #3 was on the table, but email downtown was a huge problem, that's why we took that off the table for now until we've exhausted every option.